# Pulse of userLocation when hit an Annotation will show alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations

I've been able to increase the radius of user location annotation by using https://github.com/TransitApp/SVPulsingAnnotationView 
 Now if I place a custom annotation on the map and if this pulse hits that notation I want to show something lets say an AlertView. **How can I do that?**
Here is how I changed my default userLocation annotation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if (annotation==(mapView.userLocation)) {

    static NSString *identifier = @"currentLocation";
    SVPulsingAnnotationView *pulsingView = (SVPulsingAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(pulsingView == nil) {
        pulsingView = [[SVPulsingAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        pulsingView.pulseScaleFactor= 40.0;//Change pulseScaleFactor as required
        pulsingView.outerPulseAnimationDuration = 1.5;
        pulsingView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pulsingView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, 250);
    }

    return pulsingView;

    }
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: try adding geofence to that annotation with radius given to pulsing annotation @Talha Ch.

Comment: @SatishA can't it be don't with the pulse? if no then can you share the answer on how to do it with geofencing in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding geofence to that annotation with radius given to pulsing annotation.

```
    NSString *title = "annotationTitle";
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annotationLatitude, annotationLongitude);
    CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [@"radius" doubleValue]; // Here radius is in meters, say @"500"
    CLCircularRegion *geofence = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centerCoordinate radius:regionRadius identifier:title];

    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:geofence];
```

And there are two important methods that will trigger when your location/pulsing annotation enters in specified radius of that annotation.

```
    //triggers when entering in region
        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"YourMessage" delegate:APP_DELEGATE cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message show];
        }

    //triggers when exiting from region
        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"YourMessage" delegate:APP_DELEGATE cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message show];
        }
```

This exactly looks like when pulsing hits annotation then it triggering alert.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the user location annotation moves with as the user changes position. So this will also move the geofence?

Comment: no, geofence will not move. don't set geofence to user location, but set geofences to those annotations for which you want to show alerts when user is near to them.

Comment: No, I tried your method but it's not working for me. But geofencing is not the correct thing to use as per the nature of the app. The user is moving around  and the map is moving with him so when he is close to a location say 600m away the pulse annotation will pop so I'm trying it with `CLLocationDistance distance From Location` but still now luck.

Comment: I've already worked on this @ Talha Ch, this will be the best approach in my opinion. Or you can also go with proximity fencing.

Comment: How should I add radius as per this line `CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [@"radius" doubleValue];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117806/discussion-between-satish-a-and-talha-ch).